# How to evaluate expression in js without showing anything on client end

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a static REPL that I am working on, and I have code that I need to sort through, evaling it line by line. If there are errors, I tell the client, but if there are none, I eval the whole code alltogether. During the line-by-line test runs, how do I run them so that the client won't see window.alerts, any changes in the HTML, any console logs, but still get the end result of each line (the values of variables changed in the line). How can I do this?

Comment: So you want to implement your own stand-alone JavaScript interpretter? That seems to be way beyond the scope of a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: if I can, I think I will, but if there are any easier ways to do it, I will accept them IF they don't use EVAL.